# Is there a way I can update a detail view for Django dynamically once I make a change to the model outside of views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here is what I have currently.

views.py

```
class MultipleModelView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'upload/home.html'

    # @login_required(redirect_field_name='notloggedin.html')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
             context = super(MultipleModelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
             context['jobs'] = Job.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-created_at')
             context['posts'] = devpost.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
             context['subcounter'] = SubCounter()
             context['inprogcounter'] = InProgCounter()
             context['fincounter'] = FinCounter()
             return context
        else:
            context = super(MultipleModelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # context['jobs'] = Job.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-created_at')
            context['posts'] = devpost.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
            return context

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['patient_name', 'location']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        id = randomStringDigits(5)
        form.instance.identifier = id
        sleepy.delay(id=id)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The reason why it looks like this is because I have a page where I have multiple models on it.

The job model is updated in this file once it is created.

tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def sleepy(id=None):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('upload','Job')
    working_with = MyModel.objects.get(identifier=id)
    working_with.status = "In Progress"
    sleep(30)
    working_with.status = "Finished"
    return None
```

Essentially, once a user makes a post, it gets sent to an asynchronous task where I change an attribute in the model. The model is updated properly, but I want the detail view to change once the database updates. Is this possible?

Comment: The view will return the `Job` objects as they are in the database at the time it is called. Do you mean that you want the html page to update dynamically in the browser without a refresh? You are not saving the model in your task, so the database is not actually being updated. This is a pretty unusual pattern, are you sure you need to use a task for this?

Comment: The task will do something else, I was just experimenting to see if this was possible. I was not saving the model and that was the problem. Thanks!